# Validate email before passcode sent for self-service password reset Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have self-service password reset configured through custom policies. This works fine and users can reset their password with the one time passcode sent. The issues we have are:

1. An email is always sent to the provided email address, regardless of whether there is an account in B2C with the email. We only want to send a token if the email address is associated with an account.
2. We want to provide a notification to the user if the enter an email address that is not associated with an account, otherwise they need to wait until they get the code, then enter it, then to be told the account is not valid.
3. We are also using a social login that is linked to the account, and want to prompt them to go the social IDP to change their password if the account only has a social login associated.

I cannot see anything in the display controls or the signuporsignin api to enable these capabilities.
Is it possible to meet the above objectives?

Comment: Point 2 is confusing considering in point 1, users without a registered email do not get a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a self-asserted page at the top of the user journey.

This page asks the user to enter e.g. an email address.

Then use "AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress".

This has:

```
<Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
<Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
```

So an error will be thrown if the email doesn't exist.

Change the error message to refer to the social account.

Comment: Worked a treat, thanks.